# Serializer as Field is not visible in json

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

### Model

class makitVerifications (models.Model):

```
Matter_fk = models.ForeignKey(Matter,on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name = "makit_validate")

user_fk =  models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE ,  related_name = 'verification_by'   , )
```

### Serializer

class UserVerifyCountSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
# Tried makit_validate = makitSerializer (read_only = True)

class Meta :

    model = makitVerifications
    fields = (  'user_fk', 'makit_validate', 'Matter_fk')
```

UserVerifyCountSerializer._declared_fields['makit_validate']= makitSerializer (read_only = True)

### View

class UserVerfiyCountViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

```
serializer_class = UserVerifyCountSerializer

def get_queryset(self):

    queryset = makitVerifications.objects.all()

    return queryset
```

### JSON

{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "user_fk": 1,
            "Matter_fk": 1
        },
        {
            "user_fk": 1,
            "Matter_fk": 1
        }
    ]

The field "makit_validate" which is expected as nested object is missing in the JSON .How can I get nested object  of the related model in json .

I also tried an example from the docs but  the same field is missing  from JSON

Also how to  omit/disable fields from the objected being nested in the above serializer class

### Makie Serilazer

class makitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
kamaz = kamazSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

facilities = FacilitiesSerializer (many =True,read_only=True)

class Meta :

    model = Makit

    fields = '__all__'

## Makit Model ##
class Makit (models.Model): 
    pincode = models.IntegerField()

    area = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    street = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True , null = True)

    contact_no= models.BigIntegerField()
```

Comment: please add the code about makitSerializer

Comment: @Aison  added makitSerializer and model too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From doc here: [Serializer fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

Try:

```
makit_validate = makitSerializer(source="the_field_you_find_makit" read_only = True)
```

Comment: ... of course with a comma separating the parameters